# ConTeXt equivalent of \renewcommand

Tags: context

I can use [\define](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/define) to define a new command, but how do I overwrite an existing one?

My use case is rewriting all `{\externalfigure[cow]}` to `\placefigure[right]{My Caption}{\externalfigure[cow]}` to float them.

Comment: The garden likens it to `\def` - I've never used ConTeXt, but `\def` will *always* overwrite a definition in Plain TeX.  Have you tried simply `\define`ing it again?

Comment: Do not redefine a core macro like `\externalfigure`.

Comment: the reason I want redefine a core macro is that I'm using [Pandoc](http://www.johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) which emits `\externalfigure`s in the body text. I can only change the surrounding code in the template.

Comment: or can I float specific figures with \defineexternalfigure somehow?

Comment: `pandoc` generates floating figures by default. (You need to leave a newline after the figure specification).

Comment: with ConTeXt, it gives `\placefigure[here...` but I needed `right` instead of `here`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### (Re)defining commands

`\define` does overwrite an existing command:

```
\define\foo{Foo}
\define\foo{Bar}
\starttext
  \foo  %% Bar
\stoptext
```

This prints a message to the log file that the command is already defined, but the command is being redefined. If you do *not* want to overwrite an existing command, you can use `\unique`:

```
\def\foo{Foo}
\unique\def\foo{Bar}
\starttext
  \foo  %% Foo
\stoptext
```

This prints a  message to the log file as well but retains the old definition.

```
command '\foo' is already defined
```

#### Your use case

I would not tinker with TeX macros or trying to redefine core macros. Use your editor's search-replace feature or write a regular expression to prepend `\placefigure` to the `\externalfigure` calls.

If you really want a dirty TeX hack, here's my shot:

```
\let\externalfigureOrig\externalfigure

\def\externalfigure[#1]%%
  {\placefigure[right]{}{\externalfigureOrig[#1]}}
```

Comment: thanks, with `#1`, `#2` I can access the contents in the curly braces of the command call. But what about the options in the various brackets `[]`? btw, commented about my use case above.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. You prepend all the options required for `\placefigure` and you leave all options for `\externalfigure`. And maybe append the closing brace.

Comment: `\define[1]\externalfigure{\placefigure[right]{}{\externalfigure[#1]}}` obviously doesn't work when calling it with `\externalfigure[cow.jpg]`. I always get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000]`

Comment: thanks! exactly what I was looking for :) Maybe one day pandoc will allow a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The below is not the answer to the question in the title, but it might help you nonetheless. It uses, I think, pandoc's property of directly passing through what doesn't match the input format's syntax.

Because your pipeline is something like this:

```
[ reStructuredText ]     pandoc
[ or Markdown      ] --------------> [ context ]
[ or ...           ]
```

you might be interested in the [pandoc+preprocessor solution](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/) on Aditya's blog.

In that post, he describes using `gpp`, the [generic pre-processor](http://files.nothingisreal.com/software/gpp/gpp.html), to get output-format-specific code into his Markdown document; you could also use it to get custom structural elements with custom 'translations' into your document.

```
(The plain Markdown output)
<#define rightpic|![#1](#2)>
(The output for HTML mode)
<#ifdef HTML>
    <#define rightpic|<img alt="#1" href="#2" float="right" />> 
<#endif>
(the output for TeX mode)
<#ifdef TEX> 
    <#define rightpic|\\placefigure[right]{#1}{\\externalfigure[#2]}> 
<#endif> 

I have here a picture of a cow. <#rightpic My caption|cow>
```

Compile this directly to context or HTML with

```
gpp -H -DTEX=1  mysource.md | pandoc -f markdown -t context -o myresult.tex
gpp -H -DHTML=1 mysource.md | pandoc -f markdown -t html    -o myresult.html
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks! I'll definitely look into `gpp`, will leave the accepted answer for the folks coming from a search though.